# Using Confluence with virtual hosts and mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ajp, confluence

on a test server I have installed the latest version of Confluence. I configured a apache with ajp.
But I have a problem, when I login in Confluence, I get the following error message:

```
Not Found
The requested URL / / homepage.action was not found on this server.
```

The problem seems to be known, I found following Link:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+virtual+hosts+and+mod_proxy

But unfortunately the forwards have not helped, I still get the error messages. Does anyone have any idea how I could solve the problem?

The following Apache configuration I have set up:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so

<IfModule proxy_http_module>
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration, on the face of it, looks correct, assuming that Confluence is installed and Tomcat is properly configured.

On your server, what do you get if you type this:

```
curl -D /dev/stderr http://localhost:8080/
```

And how about this:

```
curl -D /dev/stderr http://localhost:8080/homepage.action
```

You said:

> I configured a apache with ajp.

Please note that at the moment you're not using ajp.  You're proxying using `http://`; if you were to use ajp, your configuration would look like this:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

However, this shouldn't substantially affect your problem (for simple operation, accessing tomcat over with `http` or `ajp` gets you to the same place).

**EDIT**: The output from `curl` that you provided demonstrates that Confluence is responding at the correct URLs.  In fact, if I take your Apache configuration and drop it verbatim onto my server, it works just fine.

When you attempt to connect to http://yourserver/, what shows up in the Apache access log?  Error log?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your Post. I execute the commands and get this:

1)
    curl -D /dev/stderr h**p://localhost:8080/

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=838E3DA5D23E1457669E843CA2CFBBBA; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost:8080/homepage.action
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 14 Feb 2011 21:42:49 GMT
```

2)
    curl -D /dev/stderr h**p://localhost:8080/homepage.action

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate 
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-Confluence-Request-Time: 1297720104335
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F6941E06E83ABB538A8341181AED3E6A; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost:8080/login.action;jsessionid=F6941E06E83ABB538A8341181AED3E6A?os_destination=%2Fhomepage.action
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 14 Feb 2011 21:48:24 GMT
```

Honestly I have no idea what to do with the "curl" output.

You're right, usually I use the port 8009 with the AJP-Proxy, but there is no AJP-connector on Confluence, and I did not want to install a extra connetor. I also think so, that's not the reason for the Problem.

Comment: FYI: You usually want to update your question, rather than adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

in the apache error_log isn´t anything, and in the apache acces_log appears only this line when I log in:

IP-Adress - - [16/Feb/2011:18:02:14 +0100] "POST /dologin.action HTTP/1.1" 302 724 "https://wiki.example.com/login.action?os_destination=%252Fhomepage.action" "Mozilla/5.0 (xxx; U; xxx; de; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13"

Answer (score 0):

I found the Problem. In apache I set a redirect from Port 80 to 443. But Confluence generate http://-Adresses. Now I change my rewrite rules from [R=301] to [R=301,NE], and it works now :)

THX for Your help.

Greetings

Marcus